# How to toggle text on/off with a transition?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a page with text that starts off invisible with a visible heading. If you click on the heading, the text appears below. I am adding finishing touches and want to make the text slide in.
Toggling is controlled with Javascript, not jQuery. Ideal situation would be to do this only with CSS, but open to Javascript. 
HTML content below, with Javascript controlling the toggle underneath.

Already tried a CSS-only solution (below) which didn't work;

```js
function view(id) { //this reads the div id variable passed in with each 'onclick' trigger
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("descriptions"); //this will find all your descriptions MUST HAVE "description" class
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].id !== id)
      x[i].style.display = "none"; //this will turn off all your descriptions except current one
  }
  var e = document.getElementById(id); //this will toggle on/off your active description
  if (e.style.display == 'block')
    e.style.display = 'none';
  else
    e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.descriptions {
  display: none;
  height: 100;
  transition: height 0.8s;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle" id="a" onclick="view('a1');">
  Chocolate cake with Nutella icing
  <div id="a1" class="descriptions">
    How to make a chocolate cake.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please update the snippet I made you with the CSS transition you have tried

Comment: @mplungjan Hey, I should've mentioned in the question. The display in the code on my computer is already set to 'none'. Still no smooth transition though unfortunately

Comment: I did not answer, just made you the snippet you could have made ;) [mcve] - but please update your question with perhaps another snippet with your CSS. JS Can change the classname and trigger a css transition

Comment: Ah sorry! I misunderstood. fixed the css.

Comment: With the `display: none` it won't work smoothly anyway using `transition`.

Comment: Perhaps look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454643/how-can-i-slow-down-my-css-animated-text-transitions

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `opacity`, which allow you to use `transition` in CSS.

```js
function view(id) { //this reads the div id variable passed in with each 'onclick' trigger
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("descriptions"); //this will find all your descriptions MUST HAVE "description" class
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].id !== id)
      x[i].style.opacity = 0; //this will turn off all your descriptions except current one
  }
  var e = document.getElementById(id); //this will toggle on/off your active description
  if (e.style.opacity == 0)
    e.style.opacity = 1;
  else
    e.style.opacity = 0;
}
```

```css
.descriptions {
  transition: all 0.3s;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle" id="a" onclick="view('a1');">
  Chocolate cake with Nutella icing
  <div id="a1" class="descriptions">
    How to make a chocolate cake.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you remove `display: none;` for `.descriptions` ?

Comment: Works well now, thank you! Only issue is I have many headings like this in a grid format. Previously, they would all sit next to/on top of each other and then shift down if I opened up a heading in the row above, then back again when I closed the toggle. Any way to preserve this?

Comment: maybe put a `<div></div>` around each headings to keep a `block` context element

Comment: Hmmm.. tried that just then, doesn't seem to be working unfortunately. I think the issue is with opacity, the content is still 'there' its just temporarily invisible. so any text or headings below will still leave space as the content above is still there.